# Process the python dictionary to remove undesired elements and retain desired ones

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-processing, data-munging

I have a python dictionary as given below:

```
ip = {
    "doc1.pdf": {
        "img1.png": ("FP", "text1"),
        "img2.png": ("NP", "text2"),
        "img3.png": ("FP", "text3"),
    },
    "doc2.pdf": {
        "img1.png": ("FP", "text4"),
        "img2.png": ("NP", "text5"),
        "img3.png": ("NP", "text6"),
        "img4.png": ("NP", "text7"),
      "img5.png": ("Others", "text8"),
      "img6.png": ("FP", "text9"),
      "img7.png": ("NP", "text10"),
    },
    "doc3.pdf": {
        "img1.png": ("Others", "text8"),
        "img2.png": ("FP", "text9"),
        "img3.png": ("Others", "text10"),
        "img4.png": ("FP", "text11"),
    },
    "doc4.pdf": {
        "img1.png": ("FP", "text12"),
        "img2.png": ("Others", "text13"),
        "img3.png": ("Others", "text14"),
        "img4.png": ("Others", "text15"),
    },
    "doc5.pdf": {
        "img1.png": ("FP", "text16"),
        "img2.png": ("FP", "text17"),
        "img3.png": ("NP", "text18"),
        "img4.png": ("NP", "text19"),
    },
}
```

Here the keyword `FP` means `FirstPage`, `NP` is `NextPage` and `Others` is `OtherPage` (which is not a part of the `FP` or `NP`). So `FP` and `NP` are sequential and hence `FP` will appear before `NP`. Now I want to segregate the sequential `FP`'s `NP`'s from other other sequential `FP`'s and `NP`'s.

I want to process the dictionary based on these rules:

1. **Remove** all the elements that contain the keyword `Others` in the tuple present.
2. Next I want to combine those elements into one dictionary which are sequential i.e. consecutive `FP`'s and `NP`'s. So if one or more `NP`'s appear after an `FP` then the `FP` and `NP` should be combined into one dictionary.
3. If there is a lone `FP` with no `NP` following it, or if an `FP` (1) is followed by another `FP` (2) then the (1) `FP` needs to be put in a separate dictionary.

Here is what the output would look like for the above input:

```
    op = {
        "doc1.pdf": [
            {
            "img1.png": ("FP", "text1"),
            "img2.png": ("NP", "text2")
            }
            {
            "img3.png": ("FP", "text3")
            }
        ],

        "doc2.pdf": [
            {
            "img1.png": ("FP", "text4"),
            "img2.png": ("NP", "text5"),
            "img3.png": ("NP", "text6"),
            "img4.png": ("NP", "text7")
            }
           {
            "img6.png": ("FP", "text9"),
            "img7.png": ("NP", "text10")
           }
        ],

        "doc3.pdf": [
           {
            "img2.png": ("FP", "text9")
           }
           {
            "img4.png": ("FP", "text11"),
           }
        ],

        "doc4.pdf": [
           {
            "img1.png": ("FP", "text12")
           }
        ],
        
        "doc5.pdf": [
           {
            "img1.png": ("FP", "text16")
           }
           {
            "img2.png": ("FP", "text17"),
            "img3.png": ("NP", "text18"),
            "img4.png": ("NP", "text19")
           }
        ]
    }
```

So far I have tried this but it is not working:

```
def remove_others(ip_dict):

    op_dict = {}
    for doc, img_dict in ip_dict.items():
        temp_list = []
        current_group = []
        
        for img, values in img_dict.items():
            label, text = values
            
            if label == "Others":
                continue
            
            if current_group and label == "NP" and current_group[-1][1][0] == "FP":
                current_group.append((img, (label, text)))
            else:
                if current_group:
                    temp_list.append(dict(current_group))
                current_group = [(img, (label, text))]
        
        if current_group:
            temp_list.append(dict(current_group))
        
        op_dict[doc] = temp_list

    return op_dict
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm looking into this, but I immediately have bad news about the ordering.  Because python dictionaries are hash tables, that means that you cannot rely on them to be in order.  I think, because of the nature of your dictionary you intend for the `imgX.png` to be ordered by the number X, but your python dictionary won't maintain that order for you.  You can use collections.OrderedDict, though... I'll see if I can come up with an example

Comment: As of python 3.8 dictionaries are ordered

Comment: Python dictionaries do retain their insertion order as of Python 3.7 (i.e. in every currently supported version): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Comment: The input isn't valid: the key `img4.png` is duplicated in the inner dictionary for `doc2.pdf`. (Well, it's legal Python, but all but the last entry with that key will have no effect.)

Comment: @slothrop Thanks for pointing out. Just a typo. Corrected now!

Comment: false. "Python 3.6 introduced a new implementation of dict. This new implementation represents a big win in terms of memory usage and iteration efficiency. Additionally, the new implementation provides a new and somewhat unexpected feature: dict objects now keep their items in the same order they were introduced. Initially, this feature was considered an implementation detail, and the documentation advised against relying on it." And you should still not rely on implicit behavior.  If you need an ordered dict use collections.OrderedDict

Comment: CPython 3.6 introduced a new implementation of dict, **and Python 3.7 made retention of insertion order a guarantee of the language spec**. Once again, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6 and particularly the linked message from Guido: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html

Comment: @lowkey the basic problem is the check `current_group[-1][1][0] == "FP"`. This means that an NP can only be appended if the last element in the dict was an FP. So the sequence FP-NP works, but FP-NP-NP doesn't: the code won't append another NP if the last element was also NP. What if you just removed that check? It looks like `if current_group and label == "NP":` should suffice to ensure NPs are appended to the current group if it exists.

Comment: @VoNWooDSoN additionally to the above links, note the statement in the language documentation *"Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6."* https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Comment: Well, there you go.  If you're using a version of python > 3.7 than you can assume the insertion order of a python dict.  So, be sure that you never run your code on an old version of python.  In fact, you should check the version at run-time and choose to use a `dict` or an `collections.OrderedDict` based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking the last label of `temp_list`, start a new dictionary whenever you see an `FP` label, and add keys to it for other labels.

```
def remove_others(ip_dict):
    op_dict = {}

    for doc, img_dict in ip_dict.items():
        current_group = []

        for img, (label, text) in img_dict.items():
            if label == "Others":
                continue
            if label == "FP":
                current_item = {img: (label, text)}
                current_group.append(current_item)
            else:
                current_item[img] = (label, text)

        op_dict[doc] = current_group

    return op_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to do what you asked.

```
def split_on_FP(list_of_tuples):
    result = []
    interm = collections.OrderedDict()
    for name,(k,v) in list_of_tuples:
        if k == "FP" and len(interm) > 0:
            result.append(interm)
            interm = collections.OrderedDict()
        interm.update({k:v})
    if len(interm) > 0:
        result.append(interm)
    return result

print({ kd: split_on_FP((kx,vx) for kx,vx in doc.items() if "Others" not in vx) for kd,doc in ip.items() })
```

Comment: As mentioned in several comments, dictionaries are ordered now, so it's not necessary to use OrderedDict unless you need to be compatible with old versions of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```py
for k, v in ip.items():
    out = []
    for img, (pg, text) in v.items():
        match pg:
            case "FP":
                out.append({img: (pg, text)})
            case "NP":
                out[-1][img] = (pg, text)
    ip[k] = out

print(ip)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "doc1.pdf": [
        {"img1.png": ("FP", "text1"), "img2.png": ("NP", "text2")},
        {"img3.png": ("FP", "text3")},
    ],
    "doc2.pdf": [
        {
            "img1.png": ("FP", "text4"),
            "img2.png": ("NP", "text5"),
            "img3.png": ("NP", "text6"),
            "img4.png": ("NP", "text7"),
        },
        {"img6.png": ("FP", "text9"), "img7.png": ("NP", "text10")},
    ],
    "doc3.pdf": [{"img2.png": ("FP", "text9")}, {"img4.png": ("FP", "text11")}],
    "doc4.pdf": [{"img1.png": ("FP", "text12")}],
    "doc5.pdf": [
        {"img1.png": ("FP", "text16")},
        {
            "img2.png": ("FP", "text17"),
            "img3.png": ("NP", "text18"),
            "img4.png": ("NP", "text19"),
        },
    ],
}
```